# Meu tem wordpress não esta carregando

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou com problemas para usar meu tema no wordpress, assim que carrego o tema e ativo ele, eu coloco para ver ele, mas na verdade aparece outro tema por cima dele, um daqules temas que ja vem por padrão no wordpress. Eu tento abrir outro tema qualquer tb, mas ele abre esse tema aqui Twenty Seventeen, que e o padrão que ja vem no wordpress.

Comment: Tenta abrir o site em outro navegador.

Comment: limpe a cache do browser e faça reload.

Comment: obrigado otimas dicas, a dica para limpar o cache deu certo rs obrigado!